# custom deserializer isn't called despite the @JsonDeserializer annotation

Tags: java, json, datetime, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson with Jersey in Java.
Using the web API I am trying to send a POJO via a JSON file that also consists of a Joda DateTime object.
Because that is not a native Object, I built a custom serializer and deserializer for it. However, because the deserialiser does not seem to work, I send a POST request, but it isn't received on the server. Of course, when I move the date field from the JSON, it works perfectly.

The JSON being sent:

```
{"loc": [-0.1300836,51.5124623],
 "visibility":"Public",
 "date": "06 January 2014 09:51"}
```

The POST method receiving it:

```
@POST
@Timed
public String createTadu(@Valid Tadu tadu) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    Tadu createdTadu = new Tadu(tadu);
    taduCollection.insert(createdTadu);
    return String.format("{\"status\":\"success\", \"id\":\"%s\"}", tadu.getId());
}
```

The POJO DateTime declaration:

```
private DateTime date;
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
public DateTime getDate() {
    return date;
}
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)  
public void setDate(DateTime date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

and the custom serializer/deserializer:

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {

    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat
        .forPattern("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"); // 31 December 2013 16:22

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator gen,
        SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

        gen.writeString(formatter.print(value));
    }
}

public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DateTime>
{
    @Override
    public DateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser,
        DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm");
        String date = jsonparser.getText();
        return formatter.parseDateTime(date);

    }
}
```

It is clear to me that the POST method (createTadu) is not being called because a String called "date" is sent via the JSON, but it is not a valid Tadu object because that is not a DateTime called "date". I was hoping that the custom deserializer annotation would fix that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand why this method was not working. I ended up downloading the [jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) module.

The only issue with this module is that it yet does not allow custom formatters of date time and only operates with ISO 8601.

Another issue is that in the database the date time is converted to an epoch UTC time, with an added 4 zeros in the end (why the zeros..). So when fetching it back to the client a conversion from epoch to a presentable date needed to be done.